# I want to use EOF, but the result comes out as 1 when I input the integer

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Why is result 1? I don't understand it.
This code is part of a binary search tree.
I want to make a program to make a binary search tree that gets input nodes by using the command line.
so, I used `EOF`, but it's a little hard for me.
I'm just a beginner.

```
int main() {
    struct node *root = NULL;
    int ch, te;
    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        ch = scanf("%d", &te);
        printf("%d\n", ch);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        else {
            insert(root, ch);
            count++;
        }
    }
    preorder(root);
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't have the definitions for `struct node`, `insert` or `preorder` (and we probably don't need them, this problem can probably be reproducible without the unnecessary tree stuff).

Comment: When do you expect `scanf` to return `EOF`? How are you trying to make that occur?

Comment: it's the same just int main()
{
    int ch, te;
    int count = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        ch = scanf("%d", &te);
        printf("%d\n", ch);
        if(ch== EOF)break;


    }
    return 0;
} like this code. i think it's the problem about this code

Comment: i input ctrl+z by using command line to stop this program

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of **successful conversions** that take place. In `scanf("%d", &te);`, you ask for `"%d"` (i.e. 1-conversion). So on success, the return for that call to `scanf()` is `1`. If you had `"%d %d"`, you would be asking for 2-conversion (to `int`) and on success the return would then be `2`... See [man 3 scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: "*i input ctrl+z*". And what is your OS and terminal? The EOF input sequence is platform specific. Also why do you say "I input the integer"? That's misleading if it is indeed ctrl-z that you are entering for EOF.

Comment: 이건웅, Post exact input used, output seen, output expected.

Comment: You should pass `te` and not `ch` to `insert()`.  You should use either `root = insert(root, te);` or `insert(&root, te);`, depending on the interface to `insert()`.  Otherwise, you are stuck; the `insert()` function cannot modify `root` in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions. In your case, it can return `1` if a number was input by the user, `0` if the input is not a number, and `EOF` if the stream is at end of file. `ch == 1` is the expected behavior if the user indeed entered a number and `scanf()` stored the converted number into `te`. Instead of comparing to `EOF`, you should test if `ch != 1` to catch all error cases.
- you insert the return value `ch` into the tree instead of `te`.
- `insert(root, ch);` cannot modify `root`, which is initially set to `NULL`, so the work performed by `insert` is most probably lost. You did not post the code for `insert`, so it is difficult to say how to fix this properly.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node *insert(struct node *root, int value) {
    // allocate a new node and insert it into the tree
    // modifying root to point to the new root node
    ...
    return root;
}

int main() {
    struct node *root = NULL;
    int te;
    int count = 0;
    while (scanf("%d", &te) == 1) {
        root = insert(root, ch);
        count++;
    }
    preorder(root);
    printf("%d\n", count);
    print_tree(root); // print the tree
    free_tree(root);  // free the tree
    return 0;
}
```